# Saving Multiple Values in a Key with JSON

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences, key-value-store, saving-data

I tried to do it with multiple Shared Preferences keys, but it goes quiet complicated.
I saw some said that it is possible with JSON, but have no idea how to do it.

My app has many items in ListView, and I want to save several values in each item.

You can imagine a contact management app.
When the Item(person name) is clicked, you can check the values like phone number, address, and picture. And of course, they can be edited, added and deleted.

Is it possible to save values in single KEY with JSON?
So that I can load the values for each item when it is clicked.

Comment: you can use expandable list view to show atributes from a view, and yes, under one key lets say contact 1 , you can save a lot of things inside of it, like, name, phone, address, etc , if you provide some sort of code we can help you out !

Comment: I just don't know what code should I show you. I used Shared Preferences so the data is exchanged between two activities. 
If you can show me an example code of how to save and load values with JSON, I think I can apply that to my code.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to save multiple values inside a `jsonObject` you can do this

```
 try {
        JSONObject Contacts = new JSONObject();
        Contacts.put("Name", "Saul Goodman");
        Contacts.put("Address", "Ocean Drive");
        Contacts.put("Phone", "13456");
        Contacts.put("Contacts", Contacts);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So that will create a structure like this

```
"Contacts":{
            "Name":"Saul Goodman", 
            "Address":"Ocean Drive", 
            "Phone":"123456" 
        }
};
```

To retrieve this values you should do this

```
JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("Contacts");

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) array.get(i);

    String name = object.get("Name");
    String address = object.get("Address");
    String phone = object.get("Phone");

     //you also can use object.getString(""); to get the strings

}
```

hope it helps

Happy coding !

Comment: Thank you very much!
But, I don't know exactly how to use it.
The retrieving code should be inside of the Try/Catch area?
My code cannot find the object outside of the bracket.

Comment: There is no need to place the retrieve code inside a try catch, but you could do it , now inside the first try catch but In another one , the usage of this is simple, fisrt save the data as you are saving it in your project in json, then in your onitemclicklistener you paste the retrieve code and work with the data you need , Im outside home right now , but let me know if you get it to work , and dont forget to check my answer if that helped you :) it might be helpfull for others too

Comment: Post your code on where are you saving your data , edit the question and when I get home I can edit my answer to your needs